# Encrypt WordPress theme files that need to be uploaded to wordpress.org

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In WordPress, Can I encrypt the files using ionCube and Upload them to WordPress theme repository or wordpress.org?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that will not be possible as all files submitted to wordpress.org need to be in easy to read source code. Even minified versions of JS or CSS files which are used in production need to have source file versions included for verification.

Comment: the whole expectations are here https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#4-code-must-be-mostly-human-readable